# How to Download Images from new RETS CRMLS

Tags: php, rets

I am trying to download images from new `RETS` `CRMLS`

```
$photos = $rets->SearchQuery("Media","Media",$lid, array('Limit' => 'none', 'Select' => "MediaOrder,MediaURL"));
foreach ($photos as $photo)
{
  if ($photo['Success'] == true)
  {
    file_put_contents("../images/{$photo['Content-ID']}-{$photo['Object-ID']}.jpg", $photo['Data']);
    $count++;
  }   
}
```

this is not working

Comment: How is it "not working"? What do you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: To download photos use GetObject() not SearchQuery(). Consult the PHRETS documentation under Usage Examples: https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetObject#usage-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download the images from the Property class, you can use this rets function

```
$rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $listingId, "*", 1);
```

This will return the array of images associated with the particular `listingId` as image url.

If you want to download as binary image files then you can use the last parameter as `'0'`, instead of `'1'`. [ '1' is for getting public image Urls]

If the image is to be downloaded from the Media class then you can use the same function with `Media` as the class. And you should first get the listing Id from the Property class.

Comment: What is the name of the last parameter that can be '1' for urls?

Answer (score 0):

Your "file_put_contents" function appears to be attempting to parse the info headers within a multipart/mime response from a GetObject query. Rather, you'd want to do a straight http download of the MediaUrls.  I'm not a php wizard, but you'd do something more like:

```
 $photoUrls = $rets->SearchQuery("Media","Media",$lid, array('Limit' => 'none', 'Select' => "MediaOrder,MediaURL"));

 while ($photo = $rets->FetchRow($photoUrls)) {

    file_put_contents("../images/{$lid}-{$photo['MediaOrder']}.jpg", file_get_contents($photo['MediaURL']));

  }   

 $rets->FreeResult($photoUrls);
```

Also, you probably want to limit your search to MediaTypes of "Image" so you don't get other binary data or documents, like virtual tour URLs or PDFs (see [google group for this MLS that you also posted within](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phrets/ZzIRMvEoBC4/qDetnnmvHj8J)).

Comment: What is the keyword for a listingID in CRMLS?  They have like no documentation and it is very difficult to know what keywords of keys themselves are needed in order to do a search.